# How do I access the productType in a HKStatisticsCollectionQuery?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I need to know the source/sources of a particular datapoint resulting from a HKStatisticsCollectionQuery, but I am getting the error `Value of type 'HKSource' has no member 'productType'`.

I am using the option `separateBySource` in the query, and have tried accessing it like this:

```
func getDataPointWithTimestamp(statistics:HKStatistics) -> [String:Any?] {
  let startDate = statistics.startDate
  let endDate = statistics.endDate
  var sourceName:String? = ""
  var sourceBundleIdentifier:String? = ""
  var productType:String?=""
  var steps:Double = 0
  if(statistics.sources != nil && statistics.sources!.count > 0){
    sourceName = statistics.sources![0].name
    sourceBundleIdentifier = statistics.sources![0].bundleIdentifier
    productType = statistics.sources![0].productType
  }
  if let quantity = statistics.sumQuantity() {
    steps = quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count())
  }
  var dataPoint: [String:Any?] = [:]
  dataPoint["steps"] = steps;
  dataPoint["start"] = dateToTimestamp(date: startDate)
  dataPoint["end"] = dateToTimestamp(date: endDate)
  dataPoint["iosSourceName"] = sourceName;
  dataPoint["iosSourceBundleIdentifier"] = sourceBundleIdentifier;
  return dataPoint
}
```

[Screenshot of debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChJXj.png)

I would expect it to be accessible, jut as `bundleIdentifier` is.

What am I missing?

Comment: The documentation for `HKSource` only lists `name` and `bundleIdentifier` as available properties: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hksource

Comment: Yes, I saw that. How come I can see it in the debugger though? Is there any way to access it?

Comment: It’s a private property of HKSource that Apple have chosen not to expose in the public API. I think the debugger is able to see underlying Objective-C instance variables which is why it is printed in the console. You could maybe access it with https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1412591-valueforkey but that is risky because this is private API and might change in future iOS versions (and may not exist in some older iOS versions).